# Dynamic target names in Python doit

Tags: python, doit

I have a [Python doit](https://pydoit.org/) script with task that generates files. The file names change depending on task arguments.

Is there any way to include these files in the `targets` list?

Unfortunately task arguments do not get populated in target name strings.

```
'targets': ['targetfile{version}']
```

Example task:

```
def task_dynamic():
    return {
        'actions': ['touch targetfile{version}'],
        'params': [
            {
                'name': 'version',
                'short': 'v',
                'default': '0'
            }
        ],
        'targets': []
    }
```

Example command-line:

```
$ doit dynamic -v 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically modify task attributes on `actions` [(just pass the *magic* parameter `task`)](https://pydoit.org/tasks.html#keywords-with-task-metadata), or on custom `uptodate` i.e.

```
DOIT_CONFIG = {
    'action_string_formatting': 'new',
}

def set_target(task, values):
    version = task.options.get('version', '0')
    task.targets.append(f'targetfile{version}')


def task_dynamic():
    return {
        'actions': ['touch targetfile{version}'],
        'params': [
            {
                'name': 'version',
                'short': 'v',
                'default': '0'
            }
        ],
        'uptodate': [set_target],
    }
```

There is a proposed change that will allow this to be achieved more easily, see issue [#311](https://github.com/pydoit/doit/issues/311)

Comment: Thanks! A custom `uptodate` that adds targets gets me half-way there! Now I want to clean dynamic targets. Unfortunately `clean` doesn't accept task arguments, like `doit clean dynamic -v 8` (it says `ERROR: -v is not a task.`). So I can't even write a custom `clean` callable, since the task arguments aren't accepted in the first place.

Comment: I worked around the `clean` limitation by using separate callables for `uptodate` and `clean`. The one for `uptodate` is like `set_target` in your example, and the one for `clean` walks my actual output files and directories to list them as targets.

Answer (score 0):

There is a non-ideal resolution: I put my dynamic outputs in a directory with a stable name, and then referred to that directory in my `targets` list.